# How to aggregate results from making CompletableFuture calls in a loop?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I am just learning and trying to apply CompletableFuture to my problem statement. I have a list of items I am iterating over.

Prop is a class with only two attributes prop1 and prop2, respective getters and setters.

```
List<Prop> result = new ArrayList<>(); 

for ( Item item : items ) {
      item.load();

      Prop temp = new Prop();
      // once the item is loaded, get its properties
      temp.setProp1(item.getProp1());
      temp.setProp2(item.getProp2());

      result.add(temp);
}

return result;
```

However, item.load() here is a blocking call. So, I was thinking to use CompletableFuture something like below -

```
for (Item item : items) {
    CompletableFuture<Prop> prop = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            item.load();
            return item;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error");
            return null;
        }
    }).thenApply(item1 -> {
        try {
            Prop temp = new Prop();
            // once the item is loaded, get its properties
            temp.setProp1(item.getProp1());
            temp.setProp2(item.getProp2());

            return temp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    });
}
```

But I am not sure how I can wait for all the items to be loaded and then aggregate and return their result.

I may be completely wrong in the way of implementing CompletableFutures since this is my first attempt. Please pardon any mistake. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `result.put(temp);` -- List and ArrayList don't have a `put(...)` method. Please post a valid [mcve], real code.

Comment: I have not actually implemented the CompletableFuture concept in my code. But the first code snipped is a valid snippet from my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your approach of using `CompletableFuture`.

First, you say `item.load()` is a blocking call, so the `CompletableFuture`’s default executor is not suitable for it, as it tries to achieve a level of parallelism matching the number of CPU cores. You could solve this by passing a different `Executor` to `CompletableFuture`’s asynchronous methods, but your `load()` method doesn’t return a value that your subsequent operations rely on. So the use of `CompletableFuture` complicates the design without a benefit.

You can perform the `load()` invocations asynchronously and wait for their completion just using an `ExecutorService`, followed by the loop as-is (without the already performed `load()` operation, of course):

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
es.invokeAll(items.stream()
    .map(i -> Executors.callable(i::load))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
es.shutdown();

List<Prop> result = new ArrayList<>(); 

for(Item item : items) {
      Prop temp = new Prop();
      // once the item is loaded, get its properties
      temp.setProp1(item.getProp1());
      temp.setProp2(item.getProp2());

      result.add(temp);
}

return result;
```

You can control the level of parallelism through the choice of the executor, e.g. you could use a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads)` instead of the unbounded thread pool.

Comment: I have one question. To which list will Collector.toList collect the data in this example?

Comment: It creates a new `List`, which is directly passed to `es.invokeAll`. Since `invokeAll` expects a `Collection<? extends Callable<T>>`, the code streams over the list of `Item`s, `map`s each item to a `Callable<?>` that will invoke the item’s `load` method and collects them all to a `List<Callable<?>>` to be passed to `invokeAll` which will execute them all concurrently and return when all completed. We don’t need that list afterwards, so it isn’t stored anywhere. If you want to add error handling, you may use the `List<Future<?>>` returned by `invokeAll` which allows to check for exceptions.

Comment: Thanks so much for patiently explaining me the concept.

Comment: How can I wait for all the async calls to be completed? I think it is returning after just one successful call. I only get data for one item.

Comment: `invokeAll` returns when *all* have completed, as the method name suggests. The other operation would be `invokeAny`. If `invokeAll` seems not to work as expected, the problem lies in what `Item.load()` does.

Comment: Okay so, line `map(i -> Executors.callable(i::load))` gave me ambigous call error so I ended up writing it as `es.invokeAll(items.stream()
                .map(i -> Executors.callable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            i.load();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                     
                        }
                    }
                }))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        es.shutdown();` .   I guess that is the mistake.

Comment: Could this have created a problem?